# How to convert high impedance / ground output to 24V / ground output

Tags: plc

My background is from software development so please forgive my ignorance.  I have an Adam 6156EI device I can control via Ethernet, it has 16 digital outputs.  When I programmatically set an output to "true", the respective output becomes "ground".  When I send "false", the output becomes what I would call "High Z" (disconnected, neither power nor ground).  If I connect the positive side of a test lamp to +24V power, and the negative side of the lamp to the output, I can switch the light on and off.  I think the output operates like a single pole/single throw switch connected to ground.

My problem is that the downstream device I'm trying to control wants to receive either 24V or 0V in order for it to go on or off (I believe the currents are just a few milliamps, it handles its own amplification).

What can I put in front of this output to convert it from High-Z / Ground to +24V / Ground?  Or have I done something else wrong?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide a link for the device? I can't find a 5156EI on a search.

Comment: I typoed the part number, I've fixed it https://www.advantech.com/products/99c053f2-bac0-439f-aa0d-f8f991026c6a/adam-6156ei/mod_e8532774-ee7f-4515-8b5a-8537c5508b13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably just add a "pullup" resistor to the output (between the output and +24V).

The Adam unit appears to be rated at 100mA per output, which is way more than is probably required. If your inputs will work with a few mA you could try something like 4.7K 1/4-W.

Comment: thank you, I will try this out

Comment: 4.7K did not work but once I got below 1K it worked.   I'm guessing this ~quintuples the power dissipated in the resistor, so we will have to take that into account, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The NPN open-collector outputs would need to be inverted either through outboard relays or PNP transistors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for this

Comment: You're most welcome!